# Ensure all values of enum type are covered within function body

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, logic

I have a type that is:

```
export enum ApiFunctions {
  "setHidden" = "HIDE",
  "setReadOnly" = "SET_READ_ONLY",
  "setDescription" = "DESCRIPTION"
}
export type ValueOfApiFunction = `${ApiFunctions}`
```

and logic that is listening for an event on the window like so

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                    if(event.data.type === "COMPLETE") {
                        event.data.changes.forEach((change: { fieldId: string, action: ValueOfApiFunction }) => {
                            const field = api.getFieldById(change.fieldId);

//I want to make sure that within this forEach all values of the type above are covered and if not, through a compilation error
// in this case "DESCRIPTION" isn't included so I would want a compilation error being thrown

                            if(change.action === "HIDE") {
                                field?.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            else if(change.action === "SET_READ_ONLY") {
                                field?.setName("This field is now read only")
                            }
                        })

                        resolve();
                    }
                    if(event.data.type === "MAKE_REQUEST") {
                        invoke('makeRequest', { url: event.data.url }).then(result => {
                            console.log(result);
                            iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage({
                                type: "REQUEST_COMPLETE",
                                response: result
                            }, "*")
                        });
                    }
                })
```

I have explained what I want to achieve in a comment in the code block above but basically I want to ensure all values of my type are covered within the forEach logic, if not, compilation error.

Many thanks

Comment: By covered, do you mean you want to make sure that there is an if statement for each possibility?

Comment: yes that would be correct, it doesn't need to be an if statement, it could even be a switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not have a native capability to enforce the use of certain logic within a codebase. It is mostly concerned that objects are not manipulated incorrectly, rather than inspecting what the correct code is doing. Nevertheless, there is a workaround that would enable you to make sure that logic is executed for every possibility of an enum:

You can create a JSON object that holds all enum values as its keys, and each key has a value of a function, meaning that there is a piece of logic executed for every enum as follows:

```
const fieldToAction: { [key in ValueOfApiFunction]: (field?: Field) => void } = {
  "HIDE": (field?: Field) => field?.setVisible(false),
  "SET_READ_ONLY": (field?: Field) => field?.setName("This field is now read only"),
  "DESCRIPTION": (field?: Field) => field?.setName("This field is now read only"),
}
```

(The `Field` type could be something different as it was not provided in the example)

All you need to do now is to call this within your `forEach` as follows:

```
fieldToAction[change.action](field);
```

Playground link that illustrates this behaviour can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=39&pln=21&pc=3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwIJgJYDFmIDGM2EiAznAN4CwAUHHAETnAwAS2AJl0k3AF5m7AJIARAKJMANPUYs2AJWABDLgHlEAGwCe-IUwDKEgCoB9RRIxiz6gHIAZAJoy5zVjDHByhKNjAkZPrMkoYAwooiAAomIvZM9AC%209KCQsHAwOmDAcABqKlrIwOoAZlh4BMSkiIJwAAYAJFTl%20ESBFIl19PTYiDDAUCUqhDm42MBaXNRuHrnY5NgARlrAAFxwABSIwADu%20YVrcIsQECsqiACUggB8cABuENwA3DNsdiqoh1u7%200Xr5DA-IgAOZXAS3B7PJLdOiEMgAuAlcaTEwQDBVMjrKhwADaAGtgDo4L08gUiqUWpV2gBddYbJETLgAfnWY0ZYIhjymiVqtAYwnEUjpDMmLLgbMmHMRyOZADpZvMlit6QVWBdZPyjKYLFYbPZnExhTKxRKuFKRXKPO9PhsmCYABbzaWM4mURAQHZwKCqKZkXRMdVuJihCLRWLxI2Mk0y83G%20VvD7AW0Op0W11wd2e71qOB%20vSBujJOj0EpU6oZbwwVqEDaEe3nYGHbEWkRcf6A3rA6RwYbtda-YplHDV9pwRJXPmMOEUeAW1ky3lwBULZZfbZ7MmHY6nVSXG7URLdq2JunrgftoGg-dURKJF78i2o9HtHF1hvAWW96rU%20kx%20%20JIA).

Comment: ohhh this is brilliant and won't add runtime code

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the 'never' type like this :

```
event.data.changes.forEach((change: { fieldId: string, action: ValueOfApiFunction }) => {
    const field = api.getFieldById(change.fieldId);
    if(change.action === "HIDE") {
        field?.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(change.action === "SET_READ_ONLY") {
        field?.setName("This field is now read only")
    } else {
        const _shouldNeverBeReached: never = change.action
    }
    
})
```

Now if you forget to handle a `change.action`, the type will not be never and therefore it will not compile.

UPDATE : for a more explicite message:

```
const exaustiveCheck = <T extends any>(t: T extends never ? never : "One of the cases was not handled") => {
  throw new Error("One of the cases was not handled")
}
```

and then

```
    } else {
        exaustiveCheck(change.action)
    }
```

Comment: That "kind" of works but the error is not very explicit, it only says that type string is not assignable to type never. I wonder if that could be trasnformed to a function that throws an actual readable error

Comment: than you can improve with and a ternary. I will edit to try to make it better

Comment: this is my idea on the function: 
`const throwBadValueOfApiFunction = (valueApiFunc: never): never => {
 throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
} `
and then _shouldNeverBeReached
`const _shouldNeverBeReached: () => never = throwBadValueOfApiFunction(change.action)`

Comment: how do you like my edited proposal ?

Comment: it is definitely valid and it helps a lot, vote up but the other solution doesn't introduce runtime code which is a better performant solution. Thanks a lot for your help